# HP Pavillion dv5 Notebook Screen REpair

Tags: laptop-repair, hp-pavilion

My screen only comes on when my screen is half way up and it sometime turns off or turns white I think I need to connect a loose wire from the screen but how do I open the laptop to reconnect the screens loose wires? I have an infinity screen with no screws on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that the screen doesn't have visible screws. Opening up a laptop normally starts with unscrewing the body.

[Here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01550108.pdf) [PDF Warning] you have a direct link to the HP Pavilion dv5 Maintenance and Service Guide.

In there you will find exactly what screws there are, and where they are located, and in which order you have to unscrew them.

Good luck!